# anchor links doesen't link to url

Tags: html, href

can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with the code? links `<a href=""> </a>` not working, if you click on it nothing happens. I thought I left some tags open but I checked with https://validator.w3.org and there are no such errors! What could be the problem?

I have seen the other questions and answers related to this topic but they did not help me.

note: navigate to "i miei lavori" page or "my work" page
**[link](http://andreadicioccio.myartsonline.com/lavori.html):**
[minimal reproducible example](http://jsfiddle.net/L09bwoeu/)
**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>i miei lavori - Andrea</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="specchietto-menu">
        <button class="pulsanti-menu" name="btnchisono" onclick="chisonoPage()">chi sono</button>
        <button class="pulsanti-menu" style="color:blue;" name="btnlavori" onclick="lavoriPage()">i miei lavori</button>
        <button class="pulsanti-menu" name="btncuriosita" onclick="curiositaPage()">curiosità</button>
    </div>
    <div class="choose-language">
        <button class="btn-language" onclick="changeLanguage()"><img src="images/english-language.jpg" alt=""></button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="scrollTop"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up" style="font-size:36px"></i></div>
    <div class="contenitore"> 
        <p class="presentazione-lavori">Lavori svolti per svago anni fà</p>
        <br>
        <div class="specchietto-articolo">
            <!-- Firewall", un trojan per mIRC -->
            <p class="titolo-articolo">"Firewall", un trojan per mIRC</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/mirc-logo-mini.jpg" style="float:left;">Correva l'anno 2000, avevo da poco avuto accesso a internet, avevo una connessione 56k flat 12/24 con Libero@Sogno, ero affascinato da alcuni degli script di mIRC, il celebre programma di chat, molto gettonato in rete in quegli anni e ne provai alcuni, così per curiosità mi misi a leggere il codice sorgente degli script ".ini", fu così che iniziò il mio viaggio nel mondo della programmazione. 
            </p>
            <p class="articolo">La mia prima creazione fù un trojan che chiamai "firewall", per ovvie ragioni di ingegneria sociale di cui parlerò più avanti. Il Trojan era composto da uno script che era caricato nel mio client, che inviava i comandi da eseguire sul client della vittima che avrebbe dovuto caricare lo script malevolo sul proprio mIRC ma le fondamenta del trojan era la direttiva "onNotice", un evento che veniva generato quando si riceveva un messaggio particolare, il notice appunto. Di default questi messaggi erano nascosti, il client li riceveva, li elaborava ma l'utente era ignaro di averlo ricevuto, per questo motivo lo scelsi. Lo script che era caricato nel mio client mIRC non faceva altro che inviare un "notice" criptato alla vittima, bastava aprire un canale privato con l'utente target per avere accesso alle funzioni.
            </p> 
            <p class="articolo">C'erano funzioni standard per cambiare nick alla vittima, scrivere messaggi al suo posto e disconnetterla dal server con messaggi particolari, di solito quando c'era una disconnessione del client appariva un messaggio di questo genere "connection reset by peer", al posto di "peer" erano disponibili vari nomi tra cui Babbo Natale(connection reset by Babbo Natale), divertente!. Potevo scrivere messaggi su canali e chat private al posto del malcapitato e potevo cambiarli nick ma la feature più potente era poter eseguire qualsiasi direttiva sulla macchina vittima. La cosa più difficile di questo sistema era convincere la vittima a caricare lo script sul proprio client, da qui il nome che ho scelto per il trojan, "Firewall", c'era molta ignoranza informatica in quegli anni ma molti degli internauti sapeva cosa era un firewall e lo avrebbe caricato più facilmente. 
            </p> 
            <p class="articolo">Detto questo ci fù solo una vittima di questo trojan, un mio amico di chat che si fidò ciecamente di me e lo convissi molto facilmente a installare "Firewall". Tuttavia il divertimento durò poco, li cambiai nick un paio di volte, scrissi qualche parolaccia, feci coming-out al posto suo su dei canali pubblici e lo disconnettei diverse volte ma ero così orgoglioso del mio lavoro che per vantarmi li dissi tutto e subito e così dandomi della merda disinstallò lo scrip. Rimane ad oggi l'unica vittima di Firewall. Condividerei il codice sorgente ma è andato perduto negli anni.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">Windows 98, mIRC scripting</p>
            <!-- Convertitore da .wav a .mp3 -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Convertitore da .wav a .mp3</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/mp3-mini.jpg" style="float:left">Erano i primi anni 2000, avevo circa 16/17 anni ed era consuetudine rivoltare i CD musicali nel computer per poter creare le proprie playlist. Windows Media Player in quegli anni creava file wav quando si eseguivano queste operazioni e si sa che il formato wav è molto pesante rispetto agli mp3 e gli HD non erano molto capienti. Così sentii la necessità di un convertitore, cercai in internet e trovai una libreria per convertire, aprii il mio VB6 con cui smanettavo da poco tempo e scrissi qualche linea di codice. Il programma prevedeva una navigazione nelle cartelle di sistema per scegliere quali file convertire, una volta selezionati si avviava la conversione e venivano creati i files mp3 con gli stessi nomi degli originali. È stato veramente semplice utilizzare la libreria, bastava impostare alcune configurazioni e richiamare la funzione di conversione con i dovuti parametri.
            </p>                
            <p style="font-size:80%;">Windows ME, Visual Basic 6</p>
            <!-- Sondaggio scolastico -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Sondaggio scolastico</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/sondaggio-mini.jpg" style="float:left">Frequentavo il II anno del Liceo Scientifico del mio paese, il Preside aveva fatto distribuire dei fogli che avrebbero costituito un sondaggio ma non ricordo i temi trattati. Era complicato analizzare i dati delle risposte di tutti gli alunni a mano così mi chiese se potevo scrivere un programma che raccogliesse i dati e li elaborasse.
            </p>
            <p class="articolo">Allora non ero a conoscenza dell'esistenza di SQL ne sapevo a cosa servisse Access di Microsoft così mi venne in mente di immagazzinare i dati nelle celle dei fogli Excel, usai le librerie di Visual Basic 6 per accedere ai fogli di calcolo, MSDN era la mia fonte principale di informazione per sviluppare. 
            </p>
            <p class="articolo">Mi divertii molto a creare questa applicazione, credevo che avrei ricevuto dei compensi scolastici, crediti formativi o un'incremento dei voti in matematica(in cui andavo già bene) ma l'unica cosa che ricevetti è stato l'incremento della mia esperienza(ben venga sempre) e un grazie dal Preside.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">Windows XP, Visual Basic 6, Excel</p>
            <!-- Formattatore files .csv -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Formattatore files .csv</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/csvicon-mini.jpg" style="float:left">È stato molto semplice sviluppare questa applicazione. Avevo bisogno di formattare dei files csv composti da tantissime righe, era impossibile farlo a mano così lessi qualche tutorial del C++ e da lì a poco mi misi a scrivere righe di codice. Leggendo i tutorial riuscii a capire anche i puntatori e feci qualche applicazione che li utilizzava ma era per solo scopo didattico. Ora per essere sincero non ricordo quasi nulla di questo fantastico linguaggio dal momento che è stata la prima e l'ultima volta che lo utilizzai.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian, C++</p>
            <!-- Indicatori su piattaforma di trading -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Indicatori su piattaforma di trading</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/metatrader4icon-small.jpg" style="float:left">Negli anni 2012/2013 circa mi accanii nel trading online e utilizzavo la piattaforma Metatrader4, ore e ore di studio di molta analisi tecnica. Una volta acquisite le conoscenze cercai di supplire alla mancanza di indicatori per il volume di scambi nel forex e non solo. Di indicatori ed oscillatori ce ne erano molti ma mi accorsi che mancava qualcosa e mi misi a lavoro. Sinceramente ora non ricordo bene cosa facessero questi indicatori, nel codice sorgente di alcuni di essi c'è una valore Delta che non ricordo proprio cosa sia. Comunque questi indicatori come già detto misuravano il volume di scambi e quindi un bilanciamento tra domanda e offerta e ce ne sono alcuni che mi servivano per gestire il money management. Di questi ho il codice sorgente, perdonatemi se qualche file risulta poco leggibile ma quando l'ho scritto dovevo programmare da un decennio circa.</p>
            <br><a href="http://andreadicioccio.byethost10.com/files/Defcon___Indicator___VSA___CumulativeDelta__0.1.mq4" download="Defcon___Indicator___VSA___CumulativeDelta__0.1.mq4">VSA CumulativeDelta 0.1.mq4</a>
            <br><a href="http://andreadicioccio.byethost10.com/files/Defcon___Indicator___VSA___PriceDelta_Correlation___v.0.1.mq4" download="Defcon___Indicator___VSA___CumulativeDelta__0.1.mq4">VSA PriceDelta Correlation v.0.1.mq4</a>
            <br><a href="http://andreadicioccio.byethost10.com/files/Defcon___Indicator___VSA___PriceVolume_Correlation___v.0.4.mq4" download="Defcon___Indicator___VSA___CumulativeDelta__0.1.mq4">VSA PriceVolume Correlation v.0.4.mq4</a>
            <br><a href="/files/Defcon___Indicator___VSA___Volume___Percentage___v.1.5.mq4" download="Defcon___Indicator___VSA___CumulativeDelta__0.1.mq4">VSA Volume Percentage v.1.5.mq4</a>
            <br>    <a href="http://andreadicioccio.byethost10.com/files/Defcon___Utility___MM___RiskControl___v2.1.mq4" download="Defcon___Indicator___VSA___CumulativeDelta__0.1.mq4">MM RiskControl v2.1.mq4</a>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">Windows XP, MetaTrader4 Language</p>
            <!-- Alla ricerca dell'olio essenziale -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Alla ricerca dell'olio essenziale</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/olioessenziale-mini.jpg" style="float:left">Avevo acquistato da poco una enciclopedia degli olii essenziali, ancora la possiedo, è ben fatta, ci sono descrizioni dettagliate di molti olii, nelle descrizioni ci sono le proprietà e gli antichi usi nella erboristeria popolare e molte altre informazioni, inoltre ci sono delle sezioni in cui puoi ricercare l'olio essenziale per proprietà, ad esempio se cerchi la voce antinfiammatorio puoi trovare nell'elenco l'olio di eucalipto. Perchè non portare in digitale questo sistema e magari migliorarlo anche?
            </p>
            <p class="articolo">Così mi misi a lavoro, scelsi Gambas per sviluppare l'applicazione, aveva tutte le caratteristiche di cui avevo bisogno, e come database mi sono appoggiato a mySQL. Oltre che un'interfaccia per inserire gli olii e le loro proprietà c'era la parte più importante dell applicazione che consisteva nell'inserire una o più proprietà nella barra di ricerca. Così venivano fuori per primi gli olii che possedevano tutte quelle proprietà, mentre secondariamente erano elencati gli olii che possedevano solo alcune delle proprietà cercate.
            </p>
            <p class="articolo">Tra le svariate reinstallazioni, backup incompleti e pc bruciati l'applicazione è andata perduta, mi sarebbe piaciuto poterla condividere in rete.
            </p>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian, Gambas</p>                
            <br>
            <p class="presentazione-lavori">Lavori svolti recentemente con Angular</p>
            <!-- NGRX Store Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">NGRX Store Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/logo-ngrx.jpg" style="float:left;">Questa demo mostra il funzionamento basilare di ngrx, cioè mostra l’uso di actions, reducers e selector. Inserendo i dati nel form viene aggiornato l’utente nello store.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NGRX-Store-Demo" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NGRX-Store-Demo" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <br><br><p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular, NGRX</p>
            <!-- NGRX Entity Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">NGRX Entity Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/logo-ngrx.jpg" style="float:left;">Questa demo è stata sviluppata per mostrare il funzionamento delle entity in ngrx, ovviamente usa anche actions, reducers e selectors. È possibile aggiungere gli utenti tramite il form che verranno presentati e ordinati secondo l’età.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NGRX-Entity-Demo" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NGRX-Entity-Demo" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular, NGRX</p>
            <!-- NGRX Effects and Entity Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">NGRX Effects and Entity Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/logo-ngrx.jpg" style="float:left;">In questa demo utilizzo per la prima volta gli Effects che vanno prima a modificare i dati mock per simulare un cambiamento nel database, se l’ aggiornamento dei dati mock ha successo si andranno a modificare anche i dati nello store, in caso contrario viene lanciata l’action di errore di inserimento. Dall’ interfaccia ui è possibile aggiungere gli utenti che saranno listati in ordine di età.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NGRX-Effects-and-Entity-Demo" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NGRX-Effects-and-Entity-Demo" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular, NGRX</p>
            <!-- NGRX Chain of Responsibility Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">NGRX Chain of Responsibility Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/logo-ngrx.jpg" style="float:left;">In questa demo viene affrontato il discorso del pattern della delegazione di responsabilità.Sostanzialmente il componente conteiner si occupa di quasi tutta la logica e il resto dei componenti sono solo di presentazione, ad eccezione del componente per dare il rating nel quale c’è una funzione per la visualizzazione delle stelle di rating e per l’emissione del nuovo rating che scalando la gerarchia dei componenti arriverà fino al componente conteiner che farà il dispatch dell’ azione di inserimento rating. I dati da osservare hanno lo stesso funzionamento, al cambiare dei dati nello store, essi vengono passati tramite le proprietà di input ai componenti figli.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NGRX-Chain-of-Responsibility-Demo" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NGRX-Chain-of-Responsibility-Demo" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular, NGRX</p>
            <!-- rxjs combineLatest Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">rxjs combineLatest Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/logo-RxJS.jpg" style="float:left;">Non c’ è molto da dire su questa demo, mostra l’uso dell’ operatore rxjs combineLatest, combina due observable e restituisce un observable di array di oggetti.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/rxjs-combineLatest-Demo" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/rxjs-combineLatest-Demo" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <br><br><p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular</p>
            <!-- Change Detection Strategy Default Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Change Detection Strategy Default Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/Logo-Angular.jpg" style="float:left;">La CD di default praticamente viene sempre eseguita, qualsiasi pulsante viene cliccato, quindi si renderizzano i componenti ma individua i cambiamenti dell’ oggetto solo nel caso si clicchi “Change Object Reference”.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Change-Detection-Strategy-Demo1-Default" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Change-Detection-Strategy-Demo1-Default" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <br><p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular</p>
            <!-- Change Detection Strategy OnPush Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Change Detection Strategy OnPush Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/Logo-Angular.jpg" style="float:left;">Nel caso della CD OnPush, che si usa solo per i componenti children, le proprietà di @Input vengono renderizzate solo nel caso in cui l’oggetto cambi referenza, nel caso in cui viene modificata solo la proprietà dell’ oggetto il dato non viene renderizzato perché la CD non individua cambiamenti.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Change-Detection-Strategy-Demo2-onPush" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Change-Detection-Strategy-Demo2-onPush" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular</p>
            <!-- Angular Security Sanitization Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Angular Security Sanitization Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/Logo-Angular.jpg" style="float:left;">Questa è una demo per provare una feature di sicurezza in Angular, il contenuto interpolato non è interpretato e viene renderizzato completamente mentre usando innerHTML il contenuto viene interpretato e sanificato.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Angular-Security-Sanitization-Demo1" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Angular-Security-Sanitization-Demo1" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <br><p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular</p>
            <!-- Angular Animations Owl Carousel Demo -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Angular Animations Owl Carousel Demo</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/Logo-Angular.jpg" style="float:left;">Questa è una demo di un owl carousel, tipo quelle che si vedono su ebay o amazon, per gli oggetti visti di recente oppure per gli oggetti correlati.</p>
            <a href="http://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Angular-Animations-Owl-Carousel-Demo" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Angular-Animations-Owl-Carousel-Demo" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <br><br><br><p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, TypeScript, Angular</p>
            <!-- CarsMarketPlace -->
            <br>
            <p class="titolo-articolo">Cars Market Place</p>
            <p class="articolo"><img src="images/maserati_mc20_img1.jpg" style="float:left;">Questo è il primo progetto che ho realizzato con Angular, senza contare "helloworld" e altre ormai insignificanti demo. Non avrei voluto pubblicarlo su github perchè essendo la prima esperienza con Angular il codice non è il massimo, le best pratice non sono tutte rispettate e ci sono altre questioni, un refactor non è pensabile, insomma come prima esperienza va piu che bene ma non bisogna fare molto caso alla forma, non è neanche completato del tutto, inoltre voglio ribadire che non sono un designer quindi il design non è apprezzabile.</p>
            <p class="articolo">Con firefox sul mio pc il design è corretto ma con stackblitz su firefox è sballato, problema di stackblitz, usa Chrome per visualizzare la demo in stackblitz. Loggati con user e password "StanfRei"</p>
            <p class="articolo">È un e-commerce in "stile e-bay" l'utente può comprare e vendere auto ma la funzione di vendita è stata disattivata in questa demo. La gallery presenta le auto in vendita da vari utenti, con il prezzo pieno e scontato e il rating di altri compratori, c'è il pulsante per osservare l'auto o rimuovere l'interesse. Sul lato sinistro ci sono le auto viste di recente, solo in caso di login effettuato. Le altre sezioni disponibili sul menu, se effettuato l'accesso, sono 'Observed Cars' e 'UserProfile', in quest' ultima è possibile inserire lo sconto per le auto messe in vendita dall' utente loggato. Tramite le card delle auto nella Gallery è possibile raggiungere sezioni dove è possibile comprare l' auto e dare un rating, oppure vedere le auto simili a quella selezionata. Come puoi aver capito ci sono delle guardie che limitano gli accessi a delle sezioni dell' app. Usa i dati mock, se si usasse un backend reale e ci fossero degli errori, sarebbero visualizzati a schermo, vengono intercettati dall' error interceptor e passati a un servizio, iniettato e gestito dal componente navbar.</p>
            <a href="https://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Angular-Cars-Market-Place" target="_blank">github</a>
            <a href="https://stackblitz.com/github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/Angular-Cars-Market-Place" target="_blank">stackblitz</a>
            <br><p style="font-size:80%;">GNU Linux Debian 10, (NodeJS), TypeScript, Angular</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenitore-email"> 
        <p style="text-align:right">andreadicioccio1983@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function chisonoPage(){ window.open('chisono.html', '_self'); }
        function lavoriPage(){ window.open('lavori.html', '_self'); }
        function curiositaPage(){ window.open('curiosita.html', '_self'); }
        
        let scrollTopBtn = document.querySelector('div.scrollTop')
        scrollTopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.scrollTo({top:0, behavior: 'smooth'})
        })

        checkLanguage()

        function checkLanguage(){
            
            language = getLanguage()

            if(language == "italian"){

            }else if(language == "english"){
                window.location = "lavori-en.html"
            }else{
                window.location = 'home.html'
            }

        }

        function changeLanguage(){
            setLanguage("english")
            window.location = "lavori-en.html"
        }

        function getLanguage(){
            
            storage = window.localStorage
            language = storage.getItem("language")
            console.log(language)

            return language
        }

        function setLanguage(language){
            storage = window.localStorage
            storage.setItem("language", language)
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

**css**

```
    *{
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    z-index: -1;
}

body{
    background-color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    font-size:1em;
    text-align:justify;
}

.scrollTop{
    position: fixed;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 0;

}

.scrollTop:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.specchietto-menu{
    text-align:center;
}

.pulsanti-menu{
    background-color:white;
    border:solid 1px lightgrey;
    font-size:1em;
    height:2em;
    width:7em;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.pulsanti-menu:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.contenitore{
    text-align:center; 
}

.choose-language{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.btn-language{
    background-color: white;
    border: 0;
}

.presentazione-lavori{
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align:center;
}

div.specchietto-articolo{
    text-align:left;
    width:465px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

p.titolo-articolo {
    font-size:24px;
    text-align:center;
}

p.articolo{
    padding: 5px;
}
.contenitore-email{
    text-align:right;
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    /*position: static;*/
    /*right: 0px; 
    left: 0px;*/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    
    .pulsanti-menu{
        font-size: small;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .choose-language{
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 50px;
    }

    .presentazione-lavori{
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    p.titolo-articolo{
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .specchietto-articolo{
        width:100% !important;
    }

    p.articolo{
        font-size: small;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Are there any invisible elements blocking you from actually clicking the link? (If you can include a small [reproducing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem it would be much easier to help solve)

Comment: THere isn't errors in console. No invisible elements. I'll provide a small example!

Comment: @DBS I updated the post with minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `z-index` in your css. Links with negative z-index are unclickable, its better to remove the `z-index: -1` from your `*`-selector.

Or you can add an additional selector for the `<a>`-Tags to your style:

```css
a {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for the help, it was decisive but I had to completely eliminate the zindex directive on *, because even inserting a directive for "a" even with "! important" I could not click anyway. So I deleted zindex: -1; on *